# networkx: add edges from list of relationships

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a dataset (pandas frame) composed of "users" and "interactions between users", like:

```
user, interactions
1, 2 7 9 4
2, 7 1 5 7 8 3
4, 9 5 3
```

Each number correspond to the ID of an user. Each user can have N interactions, where N >= 0.

The values after the commas are the neighbours of the user.

How can I create a networkx graph from this data in a performing way?

I tried with some loops after splitting string, but the performances are very poor.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit the question to clearly state what the entries mean (does each row have 5 values?, are the values after the commas the neighbors?)

Comment: @Joel: done, thanks!

Comment: What code do you use? Can you post it? What's the shape of the dataframe?

Comment: It would help to see what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Networkx has a function to add edges from a list of edges (`.add_edges_from()`).

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

user = [1,2,4]
interactions = [
 [2, 7, 9, 4],
 [7, 1, 5, 7, 8, 3],
 [9, 5, 3]
]

# create the edge list
elist = []
for v1,v2 in zip(user,interactions):
    elist.extend([(v1,v) for v in v2])

# create graph from edge list
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(elist)

# plot graph
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]